# Shadow quality decreases after starting game in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

While I was testing my game I noticed that shadow quality decreases after I start the game. I have no idea what causes this because all settings are set to max. Do you know how to fix it? Or does it have to be this way?

There are screenshots of shadows before and after starting game:
[image]

[image]

You can see that shadows are much more pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the anti-aliasing to x8 in the quality settings and if that's not enough select your directional light and in the inspector set the shadow type to soft shadows. This will blur it out and it wont look as pixelated